# How to write a condition for FindMinimum correctly

Tags: mathematical-optimization, conditional

I would like that, when finding the minimum, the FindMinimum analyzes the variables (x and y) each time and finds q, depending on the current values of x and y. Can I somehow write this condition into FindMinimum?

I have a function:

```
F[x_, y_] = (x - 3)^4 + y^2 + q;
```

where the value of q is determined from the condition:

```
If[x <= y, q = 10*y, q = 10*x]
```

How can I write this condition into a FindMinimum?

I am trying to do it in the following way:

```
FindMinimum[{F = F[x, y], If[x <= y, q = y, q = x]}, {{x, 1}, {y, 1}},
 StepMonitor :> {Print[" Current x=", x, " y=", y, " q=", q, " F=",
   F]}]
```

but Mathematica gives an error.

What is the correct form?

Comment: Why don't you add the explicit form of `q` in the definition of `F[x, y]` ?

Comment: Your function does not have a minimum. If y-> -Infinity the function value goes to  -Infinity

Comment: Thank you. I know the problem is in the condition record. I have corrected the function.

Comment: But q depend on x or y

Answer (score 7):

I would do:

```
f[x_, y_] = (x - 3)^4 + y^2 + 10 Max[x, y];

Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

```
FindMinimum[{f[x, y]}, {{x, 1}, {y, 1}}, 
    StepMonitor :> {Print[" Current x=", x, " y=", y, " q=", 10 Min[x, y], " F=", f[x, y]]}]
(* {19.8209, {x -> 1.64279, y -> -8.25146*10^-10}} *)
```

Notice you could also find an analytical solution (remove `N` to see it):

```
Minimize[f[x, y], {x, y}, Reals] // N
(* {19.8209, {x -> 1.64279, y -> 0.}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works!

Is your entry equivalent to this?

`F[x_, y_] = 
  If[x >= y, (x - 3)^4 + y^2 + 10*x, (x - 3)^4 + y^2 + 10*y];`

Comment: Dear, @MarcoB, could you help me with this question (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276990/finding-eigenvalues-numerically-and-matrix-wise) ? Sorry, but I do not know how to contact you directly, so I am writing through this post.

Comment: Dear, @b.gates.you.know.what, could you help me with this question (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276990/finding-eigenvalues-numerically-and-matrix-wise) ? Sorry, but I do not know how to contact you directly, so I am writing through this post.

Answer (score 6):

- Add a variable `q` and change the condition from `=` to `==`.

```
Clear[F, x, y, q];
F[x_, y_] = (x - 3)^4 + y^2 + q;
FindMinimum[{F[x, y], 
  If[x <= y, q == 10*y, q == 10*x]}, {{x, 1}, {y, 1}, q}, 
 StepMonitor :> {Print[" Current x=", x, " y=", y, " q=", q, " F=", 
    F[x, y]]}]
```

[image]

- Test another complex cases.

```
Clear[F, x, y, q];
F[x_, y_] = (x - 3)^4 + y^2 + q;
FindMinimum[{F[x, y], 
  If[x <= 1 + y, Exp@q == 10*y + q*x, 
   Sin@q + Cos@q == 10*x + q*y]}, {{x, 1}, {y, 1}, q}, 
 StepMonitor :> {Print[" Current x=", x, " y=", y, " q=", q, " F=", 
    F[x, y]]}]
```

Comment: Dear, @cvgmt, could you help me with this question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276990/finding-eigenvalues-numerically-and-matrix-wise ? Sorry, but I do not know how to contact you directly, so I am writing through this post.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

q[x_, y_] = Piecewise[{{10 y, x <= y}}, 10 x];

F[x_, y_] = (x - 3)^4 + y^2 + q[x, y];
```

The exact values are

```
{min, arg} = Minimize[F[x, y], {x, y}] /.
   expr_Root :> ToRadicals[expr] // Simplify

(* {30 - 15/2 (5/2)^(1/3), {x -> 3 - (5/2)^(1/3), y -> 0}} *)
```

The approximate values are

```
{min, arg} // N

(* {19.8209, {x -> 1.64279, y -> 0.}} *)
```